# Applescript iTunes 11 play track n of playlist

Tags: applescript

Having trouble with something that used to work.  If I run:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    play track 5 of playlist "xyz"
end tell
```

it works fine, but if I hit next track, instead of going to track 6 of xyz it always goes to the next track *in to the previous "selection"* - for example the last album or playlist that was playing or another track in the same playlist that was playing before I ran this.  Further, if I let track 5 play through, it player will return to the previous selection.  It's as if this play command is just for one track...

If I run

```
tell application "iTunes"
    play playlist "xyz"
end tell
```

play starts at track 1 and hitting next track moves to track 2 like one might expect.

This worked fine for many years (iTunes 11 broke a few scripted things).  Any idea how way it behaves so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a dirty work around that uses a loop to force it manually to the track you want and resulting in the expected "next track" functionality you're after.

```
startPlaylist("xyz", 5)

on startPlaylist(playlist_name, track_number)
    tell application "iTunes"

        --set the view of the front browser window to playlist playlist_name -- show it, not necessary but good to know

        tell playlist playlist_name to play

        repeat (track_number - 1) times
            next track
        end repeat

    end tell
end startPlaylist
```

Comment: Very good.  I wrote something similar and it will do.  Too bad we have to work around like this…  I'd give you a +, but I don't have enough rep I guess.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and according to a discussion over at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5130332 this seems to be the "expected behaviour" (at least according to some). That is, if you play something and then AppleScript hijacks iTunes and plays a track, the next track should still be the track queued up before AppleScript started up.